# jQuery Code Assist for Eclipse

Tags: jquery, eclipse, code-assist

I am using Eclipse PDT Helios v3.6
I have tried using the jQueryWTP plugin @ http://www.langtags.com/jquerywtp/
I did what the Installation notes said. But in vain.
I still am unable to get the Code Assistance.
Has anyone had better luck with this?
Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just went down this same route and I thought I had the same problem.  Come to find out that I suppose I should have read the directions more closely as it states the code assistance is activated by using "Alt + /".

After typing $.e and then using "Alt + /", the code assist did cycle through the available jQuery functions that start with 'e'.

Comment: Ya I tried that too. Still no luck. I am using Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) with "jqueryWTP0.32foEN.jar".
I did exactly what was said here: http://www.langtags.com/jquerywtp/?page_id=4
Are there any other things that I should be aware of?

Comment: Yea, those are the same versions of Eclipse and of the jqueryWTP I'm using.  Those are also the same steps I used for installing.  Is it possible that you have "Alt + /" bound to another action?

Comment: No. I have it left to the default action of code completion. Is there by any chance that this is not working due to the fact that I have code assistance for CodeIgniter? I followed the steps here. http://www.gostomski.co.uk/codeigniter/getting-full-auto-complete-with-codeigniter-in-eclipse.
Is there by any chance they may be conflicting?

Comment: @RC Thank you, I am also looking for the same feature("Alt + /"). Thank you. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

It worked just fine for me, with the regular code assitance keys (Ctrl-Space), within a jsp.
I just tried with this one jqueryWTP0.34foCN.jar, followed all the steps.
It's probably a collision between this pluggin and an another one, as you suggested.

Comment: Oh really! I guess I will try it with the latest version. Got tired of trying to make it work. I didn't know that an update was released. Anyways, will let ya know once I try the latest version.