# JQuery maven CodeAssist

Tags: java, jquery, eclipse, maven, autocomplete

How can I set CodeAssist for JQuery in my web project using maven? In the ordinary web project I know how to fix this, but in maven project is different.
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Maven is orthogonal to jquery. Maven is a build tool for java. It can build project, e.g. create a war. jquery is javascript and you should include it yourself to project as other css, js, images. Maven is not related to jquery at all. And what is differences between "ordinary web project" and "maven project"? It may help us to understand your question better.

Comment: And how do you fix it in ordinary project?

Comment: I know how to included JQuery in the project. I' don't know how to config maven project for using autocomplete(JQuery)?

Comment: autocomplete is a part of jQuery UI right? Do mean [this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)?

Comment: No. You got it wrong. I meant CodeAssist for JQury in maven :)

Comment: What is CodeAssist for JQuery?

Comment: It seems that CodeAssist is an IDE feature. Is it correct.? maven is not IDE it's a console tool and I don't understand what should CodeAssist do in maven.

Comment: Like this: 
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731884/jquery- autocompletion-with-eclipse-juno-java-ee
But with maven.

Comment: Question you showed is about Eclipse. Eclipse is an IDE. Maven is not IDE, it's a build tool. What IDE do you use for your project? Or editor?

Comment: I'm also using Eclipse. As you can see in the link above it shows how to config JQuery autocompletion in the web dynamic project. But with maven it is not the same.

Comment: Are you sure tutorial from link doesn't work for you? What step can't you do in your project?

Comment: It does not have the JavaScript resources and I don't know where ot find it. Any solutions?

Comment: Try to look at this like posted in [stackoverlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518257/jquery-code-assist-for-eclipse)

Comment: Don't know actually. Try google how to add javascript support to eclipse project. E.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006934/eclipse-javascript-editor-content-assist-for-js-files)